# C++ Windows set value in array crashes program

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, crash

I'm making a VM in C++ and everything works great on OSX but when I test it on Windows it compiles fine, no errors or warnings but the program keeps crashing at the point where I try to assign a value to an index in an array. I'm not using any external libraries or anything, so I don't know why it keeps crashing.

```
THE LINE WHERE IT CRASHES:
instarray[i] = value;
```

Below I have also included the entire file to help you debug it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#define OP_EOI 0
#define OP_EOP 1
#define OP_PUSH 2
#define OP_POP 3
#define OP_PRINT 4
#define OP_ADD 5
#define OP_MUL 6
#define OP_SUB 7

using namespace std;

class reedoovm {

    private:
        string filedata;
        string instruction;
        string file;
        int instr;
        int instructionCount;
        int instructionPointer;
        int stack;

    public:
        string load_program(string filename) {
            ifstream rdfile(filename);
            while(rdfile >> instruction) {          /* Get each instruction */
                    filedata += instruction;        /* Append the instruction to filedata */
                    filedata += ",";                /* Append a comma to separate each instruction */
                }
            rdfile.close();                         /* Close the file */
            return filedata;                        /* Return the filedata */
        }

        int *instrToArr(string file) {
            stringstream hextoint;
            unsigned int value;
            string s = file;                        /* store fconv in a variable "s" */
            string delimiter = ",";                 /* The delimiter */
            size_t pos = 0;
            string token;
            int i = 0;
            int inst;
            static int* instarray;
            cout << "works" << endl;
            //instarray = (int*) calloc(instructionCount,sizeof(int));
            instarray = (int *) malloc(instructionCount*sizeof(int));
           // instarray[10];
            instructionCount = count(file.begin(), file.end(), ',');
            while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {     /* Convert hex instructions to decimal */
               cout << "works" << endl;
                token = s.substr(0, pos);
                cout << token << endl;
                stringstream hextoint(token);
                hextoint >> hex >> value;
                cout << value << endl;
                if (i < instructionCount) {
                    instarray[i] = value;
                    i++;
                    cout << "works" << endl;
                }
                cout << i << endl;
                s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }
            return instarray;
        }

        int * instructionArray(int instructionArray[]) {
            return instructionArray;
        }

        int getNextIntruction(int instructions[], int i) {
            return instructions[i];
        }

        void do_PRINT() {

        }

        void do_PUSH(int instructions, int i) {
            //cout << instructions[i + 1] << endl;
        }

        void run_program(int instructions[], string file) {
            int loop = 1;
            int i = 0;
            string delimiter = ",";                 /* The delimiter */
            size_t pos = 0;
            string token;
            int iterator = 0;
            instructionCount = count(file.begin(), file.end(), ',');
            int instructionOrLiteralArray[instructionCount];
            while ((pos = file.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {     /* Convert hex instructions to decimal */
                token = file.substr(0, pos);
                if (token.length() == 2) {                             /* Operation */
                    instructionOrLiteralArray[iterator] = 0;
                } else {
                    instructionOrLiteralArray[iterator] = 1;           /* Literal */
                }
                iterator++;
                 file.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }
            while (loop) {

                instr = getNextIntruction(instructions, i);

                if (instr == OP_EOI && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    cout << "EOI" << endl;
                } else if (instr == OP_EOI && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (instr == OP_PUSH && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    do_PUSH(instr, i);
                } else if (instr == OP_PUSH && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (instr == OP_PRINT && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    do_PRINT();
                } else if (instr == OP_PRINT && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (instr == OP_POP && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    cout << "POP" << endl;
                } else if (instr == OP_POP && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (instr == OP_ADD && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    cout << "ADD" << endl;
                } else if (instr == OP_ADD && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (instr == OP_SUB && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 0) {
                    cout << "MUL" << endl;
                } else if (instr == OP_MUL && instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                else if (instructionOrLiteralArray[i] == 1) {
                    cout << "Literal" << endl;
                }

                if (i < instructionCount) {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    loop = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        void execute_program(string s) {
            file = load_program(s);
            int * arr = instrToArr(file);
            int * instructions = instructionArray(arr);
            run_program(instructions, file);
        }       

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    reedoovm rd;
    rd.execute_program(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I've been staring at the code for over an hour now and I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: instructionCount doesn't get a value until after you use it to malloc instarray.

Comment: nulllforce's comment is very important and probably the cause of your crash. Also, you're casting an unsigned int into an int variable with the line `instarray[i] = value;` . I believe that is dangerous.

Comment: `I've been staring at the code for over an hour`  Why didn't you use the debugger? `Below I have also included the entire file to help you debug it`  But isn't debugging what *you're* supposed to do before posting a question?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had a poor choice of words. I mean't "Below I have also included the entire file to help you answer my question."

Answer (score 0):

The function has undefined behaviour

```
     instarray = (int *) malloc(instructionCount*sizeof(int));
     // instarray[10];
     instructionCount = count(file.begin(), file.end(), ',');
```

You are using variable `instructionCount` that was not initialized or at least I did not find the code where it would be initialized in the statement that allocates memory. And only after that you are assigning the variable.

Also take into account that you should use `operator new` instead of `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you are going beyond the end of an array, and it is causing a segmentation fault.  Keep in mind that arrays are 0 indexed (e.g. if the array has 3 elements, the valid index values range from 0 to 2).  It looks like you account for that in your code, but you are still going outside the range of the array somehow.  I would add a check to make sure instructionCount is not larger than sizeof(instarray) - 1, and that it is greater than 0.  You can use your debugger and / or cout statements, looking at the values of these variables to see what is going wrong.